# Eslint rule to parse jsdoc for an imported module function

Tags: javascript, eslint, jsdoc

Is there a simple way for an eslint rule to check the jsdoc for an imported module's member function?

```
/** SomeTag - useful for eslint *.
export function myFunc() {
    return false;
}

import { myFunc } from 'utils' // Reports eslint info messsage
```

Similar to how the [no-deprecation](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/src/rules/no-deprecated.js) eslint plugin works. However, this relies on what looks to be quite a complex export map class.

Comment: Did  you check eslint-plugin-jsdoc? https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc